# Hide and show the DOM elements

Tags: dom, memory-leaks, angular-directive

I have to switch between the views and i am using lot of ng-if's in my code. Can i have a better approach rather than using all ng-if's in angular ?

I don't know what to use apart from ng-if's

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way if your view  is switching on through one condition you can make you of ngSwitch

you can refer [this link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)

If above is not your use-case then you can build a structural directive for it.